# Dynamic Array in Struct in Solidity

Tags: solidity

My smart contract has a dynamic array inside a struct, however, while there are no errors, it is not running properly. Can you have a dynamic array in a struct in solidity? If not, should I use a mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using input parameter `uint challengeid` in all functions except for the one which inserts a new item into your data structure (function `createChallenge`), implies that you should:

1. Change `Challenge[] public challenges` to `mapping (uint => Challenge) public challenges`
2. Add input parameter `uint challengeid` in function `createChallenge`
3. Change `challenges.push(Challenge(...))` to `challenges[challengeid] = Challenge(...)`